# Endpoints tab on an Azure Linux VM (resource manager)?

Tags: linux, postgresql, azure, heroku, iaas

I'm trying to migrate my app from Heroku to Azure. The process is turning out to be more drudgery-ridden than advertised.

After resetting quite a few approaches, I've finally settled on setting up a Ubuntu VM on Azure (resource manager VM) and handling everything myself. I now want to install IIS on this VM, set up HTTP endpoints and configure a website on it. But I'm unable to move forward on this goal because all online resources I've seen want me to start from the **Endpoints** tab on the Azure management console.

*But there is no Endpoints tab on the Azure management console for the virtual machine I just provisioned.*

I'm now guessing this is a feature of classic Azure VMs, not v2, but the documentation, unlike Heroku's, is too fragmented to clearly describe what's what.

**So what's the comparable approach I need to take for my Linux Azure VM (v2), so as to start serving web traffic?**

More about my app: it's a Django app, it uses a pure python WSGI webserver called [waitress](http://waitress.readthedocs.org), it's db is postgresql. BTW, I can't use 'Azure Web Apps' because this feature doesn't support postgresql, nor can I install all the packages from my `requirements.txt` on it since some of them require a compiler and don't have [Python Wheels](http://pythonwheels.com) yet (a compiler is not available on the machine running the web app in Azure App Service).

Comment: There are many more Azure followers here than in Server Fault, so chances of me *actually being helped* are **realistic** here (though that may not be of interest to you). Secondly, I've seen a ton of other questions which related to some aspect of server config on SO. Thirdly, it's not set-in-stone whether my question will ultimately be helped by some programming magic, or is purely a config related question. I'm open to rewording some parts of it, if you're open to reverting the downvote.

Comment: @HassanBaig - No need to justify why you posted here (or worrying about someone downvoting your question). Just know that your question here will likely be closed, which then helps nobody. There are many people watching for, and answering, Azure-related infrastructure questions on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the big differences between v1 and v2 is the concept of a network adapter and a public IP address. as a separate entity to the VM. The thing that *should* sit between them is a [Network Security Group](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/network-security-groups/)

The power and flexibility of Azure v2 means that it is easy to create a solution that actually has no firewalling at all.

If you look in the resource group you have created your Network security group should be there. From there you can configure endpoints. (you can also look on the 'quick start' page of a VM, there should be a 'security group' link at the bottom right (I'm doing this from memory as I don't have access to Azure at the moment - so details might be slightly off)

*ETA*

v2 Security groups are software firewalls that exist at either the subnet boundary layer or at the Network card layer.

A subnet boundary SG can protect backend VMs from front end servers being compromised. So a database server only communicates via a specific port and doesn't have access to the internet (for instance)

An SG attached to a Nic is there to create application rules. For instance for HTTP you would create a single rule that allowed the destination to be port 80, allowing that to be sourced from any IP Address, with any source port.

Comment: I've also realized portal.azure.com and manage.windowsazure.com are different. 'Manage' seems to be the old way of doing things. Should I just stick to that, provision a classic VM and make use of the documentation that's available for it? V2, for my particular case, is thin on documentation (meaning there's a lot more pain to come if I try to fluke my way through it).

Comment: Manage is solely for the management of v1 VMs and services, as it has no visibility of v2 resources. Portal is the only place those can be managed. Unfortunately until the migration of all services within Azure to v2,  It does mean that you will need to switch around between both of them. This also creates issues when trying to search for solutions as most online resources will be discussing v1 (use v2 / resource manager in searches to try to hone in on more relevant results - or search for results from within the last year)

Comment: Okay, stormy seas it is. I actually successfully set up my app and migrated my DB in my Azure Linux-based VM. The problem came when I had to accept HTTP traffic - I can't find anything except for this cryptic doc on the said subject: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/ It's been many days now, and frustration level is frankly a bit high.

Comment: It may be worth going back to basics a little, create a single VM in a VNet with a single security group and use that for understanding how they work - maybe create a second VM in another region to bounce traffic to / from. Play around with it for a bit, and post a question here relating to your security group specifically (I'll update my answer with some additional thoughts)

Comment: @MichaelB - It's best not to bury details of an answer within comments.

Answer (score 1):

> So what's the comparable approach I need to take for my Linux Azure VM (v2), so as to start serving web traffic?

The concept of "endpoints" apply to the classical deployment mode (aka classic portal). But in the new azure portal, where Resource Management (arm) deployment mode is preferred over classic portal/classical deployment mode (asm), you need to add "Inbound security rules" to your Network Security Group (NSG).

You can use the new Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com), PowerShell, Azure CLI, or ARM template. I will go over Azure Portal and Azure CLI.

**Method 1: Using new azure portal (https://portal.azure.com):**

[image]
 1. Navigate to your network security group for the Linux VM you created in Azure

[image]
 2. Navigate to your Inbound security rules setting

[image]
 1. Add a new Inbound security rule to start serving web traffic. (This is an example rule named "web-rule", which allow traffic from clients connecting from any port to port 80)

**Method 2: Using the Azure CLI:**

1. Open Azure CLI
2. Login to azure: `azure login`
3. Switch to Resource Manager mode: `azure config mode arm`
4. Run the **azure network nsg create** command:

   `azure network nsg rule create -g UbuntuRG -a UbuntuVM -n web-rule -c Allow -p Tcp -r Inbound -y 200 -f Internet -o * -e * -u 80`

**Note: The above methods are assuming your resource group name is "UbuntuRG" and your virtual machine name is "UbuntuVM".**

**You can find more information:**

[How to manage NSGs using the Azure portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal/)

[How to create NSGs in Resource Manager by using PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-ps/)

[How to create NSGs in the Azure CLI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-cli/)

[How to create NSGs using a template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-template/)